# The "localhost" in the combobox in Devportal doesn't take the IP adresse of my VMware, but the URL of the page does

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I've installed WSO2 API Manager 3.2 on Docker/VMware/Linux, when i want to test the API created and published on "Publisher" from "**Devportal**", the servers combobox of selecting the URL address always shows **https://localhost:8243/test/1.0**, but I want : **https://x.x.27.197:8243/test/1.0**

When i tested the same URL(https://x.x.27.197:8243/test/1.0) on Postman it successes!

Many thanks.

[the image attached describes more the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PgEq.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try changing the gateway environment configurations in the `deployment.toml`? You can change the gateway url values by updating `http_endpoint` and `https_endpoint` values in the config.

For example,

```
[[apim.gateway.environment]]
name = "Production and Sandbox"
type = "hybrid"
display_in_api_console = true
description = "This is a hybrid gateway that handles both production and sandbox token traffic."
show_as_token_endpoint_url = true
service_url = "https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/"
username= "${admin.username}"
password= "${admin.password}"
ws_endpoint = "ws://localhost:9099"
wss_endpoint = "wss://localhost:8099"
http_endpoint = "http://<your_ip>:${http.nio.port}"
https_endpoint = "https://<your_ip>:${https.nio.port}"
```

For more information, refer [this](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/reference/config-catalog/#api-m-gateway-environment-configurations).

Comment: Hello dear, thank you for your response! you saved my day ! I tried this solution 2 days a go and it didn't succeed, but now it's okey, cuz i discovered that the time of restarting the server in this case take more time than usually take(before i exit when the reponse is delayed ).
On the other hand, should i do this or no "Generate a key store, export the public certificate from the keystore, and import that certificate to the client­-truststore.jks file."
cuz i'm not yet do this work. does this step block me in the future ?